# How do display simple page for printing product info?

Tags: javascript, conditional-content, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I'm using WP 3.1.2 and latest e-commerce plugin. Now I'm stuck at creating simple page for printing product info. It has to be only product information with not WordPress header and footer. The pop up window appears nicely but now I need to check against something in header and footer files to when not to display them.

I can't check by post id cause then I need to edit it every time new product is added. And I can't add GET parameter to URL cause then WP e-commerce plugin doesn't show product, instead it displays products page.

How can I possibly do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this much more simply with CSS and a [print stylesheet](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/). Just add `display:none` within that stylesheet for all elements you don't want visible in the print version.